# Are squares dense in C*-algebras?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Suppose that we have a (complex) C*-algebra $A$. Let us say that $x\in A$ is square if $x=y^2$ for some $y\in A$.

Is the set of squares dense in $A$? What if $A$ is commutative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in general, not even if $A$ is commutative.  For instance, let $A=C(S^1)$ and let $z\in A$ be the inclusion map of the unit circle $S^1\to \mathbb{C}$.  If $f\in A$ and $\|z-f\|<1$, then $f$ never vanishes, so can be considered as a map $f:S^1\to\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.  The winding number of a map $S^1\to\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ is locally constant (with respect to the sup norm), so any $f$ sufficiently lose to $z$ has winding number $1$.  Since the winding number of a product of two functions $S^1\to\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ is the sum of their winding numbers, the winding number of a square is always even.  Thus no square can be close to $z$.

Comment: Sorry for stupid question, what would be an example of a function in $C[0,1]$ without a root?

Comment: Oh, actually, I believe every element of $C[0,1]$ does have a square root.  If $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}$ is continuous, then the set where $f$ is nonzero is a disjoint union of (possibly infinitely many) open intervals.  On each of those intervals you can take a square root of the restriction of $f$, and these will glue together to give a square root of $f$ on all of $[0,1]$

Answer (score 3):

$B(H)$ is also a counterexample.  Halmos and Lumer showed that squares are not dense in the invertible operators on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space in ["Square roots of operators. II"](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1954-005-04/S0002-9939-1954-0062953-5/), 1954.

(In a commutative von Neumann algebra, all elements are squares.)

You might find interesting "[On C*-algebras with the approximate $n$-th root property](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/65EE591B76ADA8DF9F1C50BF5DBF09FB/S0004972700035012a.pdf/div-class-title-on-span-class-italic-c-span-span-class-sup-span-algebras-with-the-approximate-span-class-italic-n-span-th-root-property-div.pdf)" by A. Chigogidze et al., 2005.